# Bonjour Monsieur Vashe âme Érotique

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, symbols

[image: Bonjour Monsieur Vashe âme Érotique]

Clues:

Contextual graphic

y=-(4/9)x+4

Lim∞(1400e(-8㏑(x)/(x㏑(x)))

Instructions: Name that Rock Star

Mr _ _ _ i _ _ _ o _ i _ _ m _ e _ _

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't fully understand the equations but I believe the answer is:

> "Mr Bovine Joni Himself"

Which is:

> A quote from the episode [Dennis Reynolds: An erotic life](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1302093/characters/nm0000362)
>  The title hints at the episode name and the quote as monsieur vache translates from French as Mr Cow, and Ame Erotique as Erotic soul - soul being a reference to Philadelphia Soul

> OP Edit - the equation on the left crosses the axes at 4, and 9, pointing to Season 4 Episode 9, Dennis Reynolds: An Erotic Life. The equation on the right is a complicated mess, but the limit of the "e" portion of the equation approaches 1. 1400x1=1400, pointing to minute 14, second 00 of the episode. The reason the title is in French is because the singer Bon Jovi sounds like a French greeting.